# Custom Wizard Control in WPF to add and remove UserControls?

Tags: wpf, events, mvvm, controls, wizard

How best can I create a Wizard control in WPF. My tak is; first I have a Wizard Controller UserControl, that contains two buttons, i.e. Back and Next, then I have start off with two other UserControls with forms for users to fill in and click next step to the next form etc... What I woud like to know is how I could inserted this usercontrols and validate my current object before going to the next form. What can I use to get the next and previous events or is there a better solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

Im still learning WPF, and am working on WinForm project atm, so sorry for any WinForm references in this.

The wizard control could contain a reference to each usercontrol the wizard will display. The wizard will add all these controls to itsself `controls.add(_userControl1)`. Each control has its visible property set to false.

The wizard could also contain a private `enum` with a list of control names, i.e.

```
private enum CurrentControl
{
    _MyControl1,
    _MyControl2,
    _MyControl3
}
```

Wizard control keeps a reference to the current displayed control `CurrentControl _currentControl = CurrentControl._MyControl1;` Have a UpdateDisplay() method, which based on the _currentControl will only make that one control visible.

Then when you click on Prev/next buttons, it updates the _currentControl varible based on its current value, calls UpdateDisplay() to show th enext control.

This way you have a reference to all your user controls (and thus the data they contain), and thus you can validate the content and your wizard can go back and forward through them by using the buttons on the wizard, and the logic in the wizard showing and hiding the controls.

Answer (score 0):

You might be interested in the **EmailClient (ViewModel)** sample application of the **[WPF Application Framework (WAF)](http://waf.codeplex.com)**. It shows how to create a Wizard with the Model-View-ViewModel pattern and it contains validation logic which disables the Next button when the user input is not valid.

Comment: Thanks, will have a look at that.